# regex - combining multiple conditions within grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I am having hard time combining two conditions within grep.

My first condition is that 'GT' is in the middle of the string.

The strings are composed of 12 characters, so GT spans position 5 to 6.

My second condition is that no 'C' occurs before the appearance of the middle positioned 'GT'.

So far, I have

```
grep -E '^.{5}GT' *.txt | grep -E '^[^C]*GT'
```

but this would output invalid strings such as

> > GT**C**TG**GT**GAGTT

I believe the code is interpreting the first occurrence of GT as the second condition and allowing it to be outputted.

How can I make improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a negated character class `[^C]*` will match any character so for example also 5 whitespaces and would for example also match      `GT`

If the possible values are GTAC, you could repeat either `G`, `T` or `A` 5 times, then match GT followed by matching GTAC 5 times until the end of the string:

```
^[GTA]{5}GT[GTCA]{5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7ejw4/1)

for example:

```
grep -E '^[GTA]{5}GT[GTCA]{5}$' *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want:

- exactly 5 characters none of which are `C`: `[^C]{5}`
- `GT`
- any 5 characters: `.{5}`

Putting it together (anchored between `^...$`):

```
grep -E '^[^C]{5}GT.{5}$' *.txt
```

Comment: @JamesBrown In the middle of a 12-character string, `GT` would be preceded by 5 characters and followed by 5 characters, so I assumed we're counting from 0 here. The example also shows `GT` being preceded by 5 characters.

Comment: You probably don't need the `.{5}$` since the OP said `The strings are composed of 12 characters` rather than `I need to find strings of 12 chars` or similar.